# ViewScript decorator unable to set

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am following the section about "Full Customization Using the ViewScript Decorator" from this page -> http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450

In the init method of my form class I have added this

```
$this->setDecorators(
            array(
                array(
                    'ViewScript',
                        array(
                            'script' => 'display.phtml'
                        )
                )
            )
        );
```

Now in the place where my form appeared I have this:

> An error occurred
>    Application error

What am I doing wrong here? I really need to customize the appearance of the form and I just want to change the form and not the appearance of the whole page.

I have tried this:

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array('viewScript'=>'display.phtml'))))
```

Which works but affects the display of the whole page (I am using zend layout). I just need the render of the form to be passed to the display.phtml page.

Note: Is there any place in particular I have to place the display.phtml? I placed it in the view\scripts folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is as simple as this.

The ViewScript cannot be used in the init() method for your form for one simple reason. If you look at the example (and probably your display.phtml) there are echo statements like this one `$this->form->firstname;`. At this point in init() the form elements are not loaded yet!

The author therefore correctly shows this code

```
$form->setDecorators(array(
    array('ViewScript', array('script' => 'demogForm.phtml'))
));
```

Note that he uses `$form` as the object. Either in controller or view script you load your form as an object and then add the ViewScript. So in one of your controllers you would do something like this

```
$form = new My_Form();
$scriptPath = '/path/to/script/display.pthml'
// or without a path if you have a script folder loaded
$form->setDecorators(array(
    array('ViewScript', array('script' => $scriptPath))
));
```

This should do the trick.

**Update** Looking at the naming of your pthml I assume (and hope) this is a special template for your form and *not* your whole layout file. If you use your whole layout file then of course if will render the whole page!

Comment: Decorators are only invoked at render-time. You can add them before, after or during adding elements.

Comment: I wish this nuance had been made more obvious somewhere in the documentation. I've spent too long wondering if my attempts to set up the ViewScript decorator within init() were failing because I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When working with view scripts, I find it's best to make any such changes at the view level.

Ignore the "ViewScript" decorator details in your form and set them from the view, eg

```
<?php echo $this->form->setDecorators(array(
    'PrepareElements',
    array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '_forms/display.phtml'))
)) ?>
```

The location of the `display.phtml` file is relative to the module's view scripts folder. If this is just the default module (under the `application` folder), the script in my example will be located at `application/views/scripts/_forms/display.phtml`

Comment: I did this in the form init() and it changed the page. I really just want to change the output of the render of the form and not the complete page. Is there no way of doing this?

Comment: @AntonioCS Have you tried from the view as outlined in my answer? What does your `display.phtml` file look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove HTML tags like `<dt>` or `<dd>` (labels and viewscript) you can use methods `removeDecorator('HtmlTag')` or `removeDecorator('Label')`